a small doubt in the proof of the quantitative form of the prime number theorem
I have been studying the proof of the prime number theorem in the quantitative form as in Theorem 6.9 of Montgomery & Vaughan's book "Multiplicative Number Theory, which focuses on proving that there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\psi(x) = x + O\Big(\frac{x}{\exp(c\sqrt{\log x})}\Big)$, uniformly for $x\geq 2$.
So, the whole proof is pretty straightforward to follow; at the very end, they make the comment that the error term which they obtain as being $\ll x(\log x)^2 \exp(-\sqrt{c\log x})$ is $\ll x \exp (-c\sqrt{\log x})$, since it may be supposed that $0<c<1$. I don't quite follow this implication about how the $\log x$ term is getting absorbed and the $c$ is coming outside the square root.
Any hints or pointers to clear this step will be highly helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Let's clarify what we need to prove: it's asserted that if $0<c<1$ then
$$
x(\log x)^2 \exp(-\sqrt{c\log x}) \ll x \exp (-c\sqrt{\log x}),
$$
which is equivalent to each of
\begin{align*}
(\log x)^2 \exp(-\sqrt{c\log x}) &\ll \exp (-c\sqrt{\log x}) \\
(\log x)^2  &\ll \exp(\sqrt{c\log x})\exp (-c\sqrt{\log x}) \\
(\log x)^2  &\ll \exp( (\sqrt c-c)\sqrt{\log x}).
\end{align*}
Note that $\sqrt c-c>0$, so this might already be convincing; but let's do the next step anyway because it gives us a chance to invoke a lemma that should be in every big-O-user's repertoire:
If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both tend to $\infty$ and $\log f(x)=o(\log g(x))$, then $f(x)=o(g(x))$. (Valuable exercises: prove this lemma from the definition of little-$o$, and show that the converse doesn't hold and that the lemma becomes invalid if little-$o$ is replaced by big-$O$.)
Noting that
$$
\log( (\log x)^2 ) = 2\log\log x = o( (\sqrt c-c)\sqrt{\log x} ) = o( \log( \exp( (\sqrt c-c)\sqrt{\log x}) ) ),
$$
the lemma now implies that
$$
(\log x)^2  = o( \exp( (\sqrt c-c)\sqrt{\log x}) ),
$$
and little-$o$ is even stronger than $\ll$.

That is a very result to know, thanks a lot. And for the explanation too. Thanks
